# Create a database for another Android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-support-library

I am making an Android library project for fetching location of device. I want to store this information in database. When my external application uses this library, it will fetch values from database. I need to make the database specific to the application using library. So that database remain within the app. I am unable to create database at runtime in the library code.

Comment: Show us the code please .

Comment: Firstly, database issue you can create simple database as using sqlite. It is by default provided with android librarires. Also for better experience you can go for ORMLite framework based on sqlite and its lightweight good to use.Secondly,to use in another project check dependency issues have u implemented dependency correctly.